# Why isn't my `addEventListener` working?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am creating a Tic Tac Toe game.

Upon the page loading, html will be reset to the 'start page'. So I add it back easily later on, the original html of the body has been stored in a variable.

When the user clicks the 'start' button, the original HTML is then loaded back up.

Why is this not working right now?

```
(function () {

    'useStrict';


// Grab original HTML and hold it as a variable
    var originalHTML = document.body.innerHTML;


// When the page loads, the startup screen should appear.
    window.onload = function() {
        document.body.innerHTML = '<div class="screen screen-start" id="start"><header><h1>Tic Tac Toe</h1><a href="#" class="button">Start game</a></header></div>';
    };



// Add programming, so that when the player clicks the start button the start screen disappears, the board appears, and the game begins.
    function loadBoard() {
        document.body.innerHTML = originalHTML;
    };

    document.querySelector('button').addEventListener("click", loadBoard);


})();
```

The error is: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null?

Comment: It seems that the `querySelector` function can't find the `button` element. Perhaps you meant to type `.button`? This would make sense, since `button` is a class and should be identified as such when you use `querySelector`.

Comment: Strange, what you said makes complete sense but it's still not working :s

Comment: You set the HTML `onload`, but don't wait until then to try to attach the event listener. Also, it's `use strict`, not `useStrict`.

Comment: Don't do this. There are much better ways to restore the state of your app.

Comment: Can you please suggest a better way, @torazaburo?

Comment: @torazaburo please suggest something

Answer (score 1):

```
window.onload = function() {
        document.body.innerHTML = '<div class="screen screen-start" id="start"><header><h1>Tic Tac Toe</h1><a href="#" class="button">Start game</a></header></div>';
document.querySelector('a').addEventListener("click", loadBoard);
    };
```

Comment: Can you please explain why the event handler works `onload` but not on it's own?

Comment: an <a> element may not be created when your code `document.querySelector('a').addEventListener("click", loadBoard);` running,so assign the click envent after the code `document.body.innerHTML =...`